# How can I put alt attribute in img cmb2 inside a loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, cmb2

this is my first question in stackoverflow. I tried many ways of put the alt attribute but I can't did it. This is my code of customs fields (CMB2)

```
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'edc_campos_homepage' );
function edc_campos_homepage() {
    $prefix = 'edc_home_page_';
    $id_home = get_option('page_on_front');
    $edc_campos_homepage = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'           => $prefix . 'homepage',
        'title'        => esc_html__( 'Campos de la pagina de Inicio', 'cmb2' ),
        'object_types' => array( 'page' ), // Post type
        'context'      => 'normal',
        'priority'     => 'high',
        'show_names'   => true, // Show field names on the left
        'show_on'      => array(
            'id' => array( $id_home ),
        ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
    ) );
    $edc_campos_homepage->add_field( array(
        'name'         => esc_html__( 'Países participantes', 'cmb2' ),
        'desc'         => esc_html__( 'Cargue las banderas aquí', 'cmb2' ),
        'id'           => $prefix . 'banderas',
        'type'         => 'file_list',
        'preview_size' => array( 100, 100 ), // Default: array( 50, 50 )
    ) );
}
```

And this is my code from loop

```
 <div id="contenedorPaises" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <?php 
    $banderas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'edc_home_page_banderas',true );
    foreach($banderas as $id=> $bandera){ ?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="product-wrapper">
          <?php 
            $bandera = wp_get_attachment_image_url($id, 'full');
            $image_alt = get_post_meta($bandera, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
           ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $bandera ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="<?php echo $image_alt ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
```

And this is the source page

```
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 316.6px;">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="product-wrapper">
    <img src="http://domainName/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/el-salvador.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the source page (see the picture)

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdefB.png)

Comment: Show us the page source so we can see what that outputs **just that specific part of the page**

Comment: I just updated the post, thanks!

Comment: Look up `browser` and `page source` - `Right click -> View Page Source`

Comment: I just updated the post, again. Thanks

Comment: Then `$image_alt` must be empty Which probably means `get_post_meta($bandera, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);` is wrong or also returning nothing

Comment: In fact `get_post_meta($bandera, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)` returning nothing, that code is an example that I tried to include in my loop, but is not working, Do you have any idea of how can I get alt attribute?

Comment: I'm spotting a prefixing underscore in `_wp_attachment_image_alt`. I don't know CMB2, so this might be correct or it might be an error. Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow.